Analytic vector bundle from an etale local system is algebraic?
Suppose $X$ is an algebraic variety over $\mathbb C$, and $\mathbb L$ is a $\mathbb Q_p$-local system on $X_{et}$, then it corresponds to a representation $\pi_1(X_{et})\to GL_n(\mathbb L)$. Since etale fundamental group is the profinite completion of topological fundamental group, we see that $\mathbb L$ induces a topological local system, denoted by $\mathbb L'$. Then if we fix an injection $\mathbb Q_p\to \mathbb C$, then use this to construct $\mathbb L'\otimes_{\mathbb Q_p} \mathcal O_{X}^{an}$, it's an analytic vector bundle. I want to ask is it algebraic?

Yes, because it is the analytification of the vector bundle obtained from $\mathbb{L}\otimes\mathcal{O}{X{\rm et}}$ by descent (vector bundles on $X_{\rm et}$ and on $X$ are the same). Indeed, there is a natural map between the two, and to check it is an isomorphism, we may do so etale locally on $X$, and therefore reduce to the case $\mathbb{L}$ being constant, in which case it's obvious.

Sure, sorry for the mistake--- my original question is $\mathbb Q_p$-local system, which cannot be trivialized over etale covers. I have edited it.

The underlying vector bundle of a $\mathbb{C}$-local system is always algebraic, by Deligne's Riemann-Hilbert correspondence (LNM 163).

@PiotrAchinger Thanks, may I ask what is LNM 163? Could you give the full name of the paper?

LNM = Springer series of Lecture Notes in Mathematics. So LNM 163 = Equations Différentielles à Points Singuliers Réguliers by Deligne.
